# How do I run multiple ruby scripts sequentially on my local machine?

Tags: ruby, delayed-job

I have about 5 or 6 ruby scripts I want to run, right after each other. These are all on my local machine (OS X) and won't be run on a server.

Each takes about 15 minutes to run, and I don't want to have to wait for each one to finish before running the others manually.

Without using something as heavy as delayed_job or some other queueing gem, how can I achieve this?

Or should I go through the hassle of setting up sidekiq or something else?

Thanks.

P.S. It would be nice to restart the script if one of them times out (I am doing web crawling, so keeping an HTTP connection open sometimes gives me issues) - which happens occasionally.

Comment: Write another small script that calls the other scripts.

Comment: Hrmm....what would that look like? That sounds very clever - just not sure how to write a script to call another script. Also, how would I handle error handling?

Comment: [Rake](http://rake.rubyforge.org/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Zabba said, writing a script to call your scripts is a good solution.  You could write a simple Bash script for this, or use Ruby as shown below:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

SCRIPTS=%w{s1.rb s2.rb s3.rb}
MAX_RETRIES=3

SCRIPTS.each do |script|
  MAX_RETRIES.times do |n|
    system "ruby #{script}"
    break if $?.exitstatus == 0
  end
end
```

This uses the `system` call in Ruby, and `$?` is the Process::Status object that you can use to capture the exit codes of your scripts.

For this to work properly, you just need to make sure that your scripts return an exit code (using the `exit` command) of `0` when successful, or something non-zero, e.g. `1` on failure.

There are some obvious security concerns running `system`, so unless you're on your local machine set your permissions accordingly :)

Comment: The ruby docs for `exit` aren't all that useful. Do I have to tell my script to return a particular `exit` status code (depending on the results), or will ruby do that automagically?

Comment: Your scripts will implicitly return 0 or 1 on success / failure, respectively. But you can pass exit an explicit value if needed, e.g. exit 1

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your ruby scripts return a non-zero error code when a failure occurs, your bash script could be as simple as the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

ruby script1.rb
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
    ... handle script1 errors here ...
fi

ruby script2.rb
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
    ... handle script2 errors here ...
fi

... etc, etc ...
```

Comment: Thanks. I prefer the ruby script version though.

Answer (score 0):

just execute them all from the terminal on one line. This is almost certainly the lightest weight solution.

```
ruby script0.rb; ruby script1.rb; ruby script2.rb; ruby script3.rb
```

This won't restart a script if it times out, but you should probably be handling that in the script itself...